# Number of relations on (A cross B)?

Tags: combinatorics, relations, function-and-relation-composition

Is the number of relations on $A \times B$ the same as the number of relations from $A$ to $B$?

Can anybody clear this doubt with some examples? In my notes, I have written the number of relations on $A \times B$ as $2^{(mn)^2}$ and number of relations from $A$ to $B$ as $2^{mn}$. But some friends are arguing both are same and answer is $2^{mn}$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are right.

---

A relation from $A$ to $B$ is a subset of $A\times B$.

A (binary) relation on a set $X$ is a relation from $X$ to $X$ hence is a subset of $X\times X$.

So a (binary) relation on set $A\times B$ is a subset of $(A\times B)\times(A\times B)$.

---

See [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/relations-on-sets) for example.

I can imagine though that sometimes mathematicians are kind of sloppy by the use of this terminology. So do not put too much trust in it and inform.

Comment: Any objections to this Statement if no I will consider this as ok

Comment: Aayat. Of course you can wait for a while, but chances are small (I think) that someone will react on your comment by raising an objection.

Comment: Done ✅ thanks for the help